# Select ID w/jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a table with rows generated via a loop. Each TR has a unique ID. 
How do I select that ID when I click span with **.clickMe** class?

```
<tr id="244">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><span class="clickMe"</td>
</tr>
<tr id="4554">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><span class="clickMe"</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF the structure is always going to be the same you could just do:

`var theId = this.parentNode.parentNode.id`

If its not always going to be the same then you could do:

`var theId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');`

So putting it all together:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){

  var theId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // or the standard DOM approach

  // other stuff
});
```

Also your Id's should not begin with numbers as per the spec.

Comment: I forgot... Yes, shall I add add a prefix and then strip it somehow or shall I place them in a class tag?

Comment: @santa: Id add a prefix and then just `substr` it. Or you could use the html5 data attributes.